# How to find usb port using in C#

Tags: c#

I want to communicate with USB port. How can I find my USB device (Weingscale)?

```
public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;

#region SET YOUR USB Vendor and Product ID!

public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder =
    new UsbDeviceFinder(0x15D9, 0x8A4C); // specify vendor, product id

#endregion

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

    try
    {
        // Find and open the usb device.
        MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

        // If the device is open and ready
        if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

        // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb)
        // it will have an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the
        // variable will be null indicating this is an interface of a
        // device.
        IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
        if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
        {
            // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used,
            // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

            // Select config
            wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

            // Claim interface
            wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(1);
        }

        // open read endpoint
        UsbEndpointReader reader =
            MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep02);

        // open write endpoint
        UsbEndpointWriter writer =
            MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep03);

        // write data, read data
        int bytesWritten;
        ec = writer.Write(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 }, 2000, out bytesWritten); // specify data to send

        if (ec != ErrorCode.None)
            throw new Exception(UsbDevice.LastErrorString);

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
        {
            int bytesRead;

            // If the device hasn't sent data in the last 100 milliseconds,
            // a timeout error (ec = IoTimedOut) will occur.
            ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 100, out bytesRead);

            if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception("No more bytes!");

            // Write that output to the console.
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone!\r\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine((ec != ErrorCode.None ? ec + ":" : String.Empty) + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (MyUsbDevice != null)
        {
            if (MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
            {
                // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
                // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the
                // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is
                // an interface of a device; it does not require or support
                // configuration and interface selection.
                IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                {
                    // Release interface
                    wholeUsbDevice.ReleaseInterface(1);
                }

                MyUsbDevice.Close();
            }
            MyUsbDevice = null;

            // Free usb resources
            UsbDevice.Exit();
        }

        // Wait for user input..
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output of above code is *"Device not found."*.

Comment: @Manfred please give this question a close vote

Comment: @LKRAJ what is your *actual* question? How to talk to your device or how to play with USB ports? You don't need access to USB APIs to talk with a device, you need the device's API. Most devices use a common set of drivers or appear as serial ports. How does your device appear in Device Manager?

Comment: @nkosi post that comment as an answer. Whatever he is trying to do, that definitely gives him the basic knowledge and can be voted as answer.

Comment: @Cataklysim it is a dupe and as such I should not be posting it as an answer. The question should be voted closed as a duplicate and point to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Nkosi oh ok. Im still doing bad to see if it's a dublicate or not. In this example I thought of your comment as documentation source that could help him understand